# Google App Engine Cloud Tasks - 503 Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

I have a push queue with the following configuration:

```
Rate limits
-----------------
Max rate - 500/s
Max concurrent - 8
Max burst size - 100

Retry parameters
---------------------------
Max attempts - 3
Min interval - 5s
Max interval - 3600s
Max doublings - 16
Max retry duration - Unlimited
```

I have a following service performing tasks from the queue:

```
runtime: python38
service: tasks

instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
  idle_timeout: 10m

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

**Problem:**

For the test, I set each task execution time ~60s.
Once I put a bunch of tasks into the queue (lets say 1000)
some of them fail with the following error - `503 Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.` http request is waiting for about 30s before returning 503 error.

**What I expected to happen:**

Tasks should wait in the queue until service is ready to perform them, no errors should occur, tasks should not be lost!!!

**Other information (workarounds you have tried, documentation consulted, etc):**

Also I see 502 errors in service logs.
I've tried to play with Max concurrent queue param, instance_class, scaling types.

If I put smaller bunch of tasks to the queue (~100) no errors occur.
I put tasks to the queue with a simple for loop